# How fibers can exist in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, fibers

I know that my question is more academic than a real issue. In most cases a thread implementation with Fiber-like logic would be OK. But is there any way to implement Fibers as they are [described](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29) in the JVM?

Is there any framework that is missing me to achieve that?

Comment: A Google search ("java" & "fiber") will give you answers - e.g. http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/.  Please attempt to do your own research before you ask an SO question.

Comment: Sometimes fibers are also known as user-mode scheduling, maybe that can help you.

Comment: @Stephen C I have seen Jetlang, even it names its therads as "Fibers" they are not. They are small rescheduled threads. No co-operation is involved.

Comment: @Chris O how can this be implemented. Since all threads are executed by the same user in the JVM

Comment: OK ... so what about all of the other hits?  Don't any of them answer your question?

Comment: @Stephen C Most of them, are using a thread-like logic (that i mentioned) that's why i asked. To make sure if there is anything else that I might be missing.

Comment: @BagosGiAr: To make your question more constructive, please edit it to cite what approaches you have examined and how each comports with your expectations.

Comment: OK ... so what about the approaches that you found that aren't thread-like logic?  Don't any of them answer your question?  Unless you FIX your question to make it more constructive it is likely to get closed ...

Comment: @Stephen C Well yes it does http://code.google.com/p/coroutines/ and as you mentioned http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/ are really close enough implementations. And in a real world scenario these might be enough. My point is to make sure if there is an other way (maybe more low-level) to implement fibers.

Comment: Not without changing the JVM - e.g. the first hit! http://weblogs.java.net/blog/forax/archive/2009/11/19/holy-crap-jvm-has-coroutinecontinuationfiber-etc

Answer (score 3):

There were/are Java EE frameworks, that enable to have a class with normal control flow like a Java SE application, and thus maintain state. To function over HTTP at specific points the classes instance is serialized, a response is made to the client, and on the next request the instance is deserialized and continues. *This is not a general purpose coroutine solution, and I would certainly not call fibers.*

Unfortunately its name slips my mind. But that was a specific case of running one single coroutine transfering control to the framework coroutine.

**AOP** offers another mean to switch control. Could maybe be used to implement fibers.

Comment: I've never relate AOP to a Fiber implementation. I can think of some close enough solutions but I am not sure if this would be enough to be called as Fibers.